# Alpha Numeric Primary

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was planning to have a primary key with 'LIBBOOKS-1214' but I cant do it. I want it whenever I will input an another info it will generate that as my primary key.

Here is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE tblBookInfo
(
AccessionNumber NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @RandomNumber NVARCHAR(10);
DECLARE @AccNo NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Upper INT;
DECLARE @Lower INT

SET @Lower = 1
SET @Upper = 9999

Select @RandomNumber = Round (((@Upper - @Lower -1)* RAND() + @Lower), 0)

SET @AccNo = 'LIBBOOKS' + @RandomNumber
SELECT @AccNo

Set AccessionNumber = @AccNo
SELECT AccessionNumber
)
```

Thank you for your help! Much appreciated. I'm still a newbie in SQL-Server.

Comment: I've put your code in to a code block. It would however be beneficial if the code you post made sense.

Comment: Your code is not valid SQL. Fix that first. SQL Server is capable of primary keys whose type is `(N)VARCHAR(x)`.

Comment: Your random number in no way guarantees uniqueness which is required for a primary key. And if the prefix is always LIBBOOKS is it really necessary to store that part in the database?

Comment: If you want to make a column the primary key, note that any index entry can be **at most 900 bytes** in size (should be much less to be efficient). Since `varchar(max)` can be 2 GB, you **cannot** index such a column. Use a **more appropriate** like `Varchar(20)` instead. Don't overuse/abuse `varchar(max)` - use it only when absolutely needed - see [What's the Point of Using VARCHAR(n) Anymore?](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/whats-the-point-of-using-varchar%28n%29-anymore/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this in SQL Server would be to have:

- a column if type `INT IDENTITY` which automagically handles the numeric part of your identifier by producing sequential numbers when rows are inserted into your table

  ```
  CREATE TABLE dbo.tblBookInfo
   ( ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
      .... other columns here.....
   )
  ```
- a **computed, persisted** column that combines that alphanumeric prefix and the identity column - something like

  ```
  ALTER TABLE dbo.tblBookInfo
  ADD AlphaNumID AS 'LIBBOOKS-' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(5)) PERSISTED
  ```

It's up to you whether you define the primary key to be on the `ID` column (that would be my preference - there's really no need to include that prefix into every index entry and store it many times over) or whether you really must have it on the `AlphaNumID` column. To speed searches up, you can always put a separate nonclustered index on `AlphaNumID` , too.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build a table that generates it's own `PRIMARY KEYS`, you need to do something like this:

```
USE tempdb
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.MyTable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE MyTable

CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
    BookID  INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    Title   VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_MyTable PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        BookID ASC
    )
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO MyTable (Title) VALUES
('SQL Syntax Explained'),
('Sensible Posting explained')

SELECT *
FROM MyTable
```

It should be noted that a `CLUSTERED INDEX` will be built on the `PRIMARY KEY` as is the default behaviour in `SQL Server` when working through an create table `SSMS GUI`. It is NOT mandatory.

It really is quite difficult to guess at what it is you're trying to achieve with your code. If you could explain it a little better, we could certainly help you.

As a footnote regarding `PRIMARY KEYS`, it is regarded by many as best practice to use an integer type number (`TINYINT`, `SMALLINT`, `INT`, `BIGINT`) as your `PK`. When you do this, you are said to be creating an **Artificial Primary Key**. In a nutshell, they are manageable values that `INDEX` well and perform well on `JOINS` of equality.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use a concatenated primary key consisting of 2 columns, one will hold the Alpha string the other the numeric.  Then your numeric column could use an Identify field as proposed by MarkD.

Another option is to use a varchar field and write a function that determines the numeric value for the alpha-numeric string.  E.g. you pass into the function 'LIBBOOKS' and it returns a string 'LIBBOOKS- then you insert this.  You could do this in a trigger that fires on each insert.

In you psudoe code you mix the create table and the start of a function to create a alpha-numeric string.  If you go done this path create you table as normal and then write a peice of code to create the primary key.  Finally puyt it together, e.g. create a trigger to call the code to create the primary key or do this in you application, etc depending on your design.

If you are going to use a random value remember to check if for uniqueness before attempting to insert with it.